# WiX bundle RegistrySearch always fails

Tags: wix

I am trying to use a registry search in a WiX bundle to detect if the Microsoft Access Database Engine is installed and then conditionally install it based on the result:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine" Result="exists" Variable="AccessDbInstalled" />

<PackageGroup Id="AccessDb">
  <ExePackage
      Id="AccessDb14"
      Cache="no"
      Compressed="yes"
      PerMachine="yes"
      Permanent="yes"
      Vital="yes" 
      SourceFile="Prereqs\AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe"
      InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart"
      InstallCondition="NOT AccessDbInstalled">
  </ExePackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

However the log shows the registry search as always failing, even though I can plainly see the key in the registry:

```
[77E4:51D8][2021-10-14T16:45:11]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine'
[77E4:51D8][2021-10-14T16:45:11]i000: Setting numeric variable 'AccessDbInstalled' to value 0
```

[image]

I have other registry searches that work fine, just not this one?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Win64="yes"`. The search defaults to the 32-bit registry hive. You need to tell Burn you want the 64-bit registry.

Comment: Perfect! Knew I was missing something